# Spring: Could not autowire. No beans of ... type found

Tags: java, spring

I have problems with autowiring in Spring.

I have dao class for AccessLevel object like this:

Interface:

```
public interface AccessLevelDAO {

    public AccessLevel select(Integer id);
}
```

It's implementation:

```
@Repository
public class AccessLevelDAOImpl implements AccessLevelDAO {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public void AccessLevelDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    private Session currentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS,
                   isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
    public AccessLevel select(Integer id) {
        return (AccessLevel) currentSession().createCriteria(AccessLevel.class).add(Restrictions.idEq(id)).uniqueResult();
    }
}
```

And service class which using this DAO class:

Interface:

```
public interface UserServices {

    String getUserAccessLevel(String username);

    AuthorizationResponseDTO authorize(String username, String password);
}
```

And implementation:

```
@Service
public class UserServicesImpl implements UserServices {

    @Autowired private AccessLevelDAO accessLevelDAO;
    @Autowired private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    public String getUserAccessLevel(String username) {
        User user = userDAO.select(username);
        return accessLevelDAO.select(user.getAccessLevel()).getAccessLevel();
    }

    @Override
    public AuthorizationResponseDTO authorize(String username, String password) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to @Autowire accessLevelDAO and userDAO i get error message "Could not autowire. No beans of "AccessLevelDAO" type found".

Spring config includes component scan definition:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.core"/>
```

Comment: Are `AccessLevelDAO` and its implementation in package `com.core` or in another package inside `com/core` folder?

Comment: It's in inner package com.core.dao, implementation in package com.core.dao.impl

Comment: Full error log would be more useful, perhaps earlier Spring failed to autowire `SessionFactory` in `AccessLevelDAOImpl` and this caused unavailability of the bean.
@LuiggiMendoza I think spring  scans all packages that have this as root, so as long as the files are in package com.core or below everything is OK

Comment: I've tested database access. Session factory is OK. I can get access to database and use CRUD operations.

Comment: @4ernik Again, post logs from application initialization - without them it's hard to say anything